# Postfix Address Binding

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I have done extensive research to try and figure out why the smtp_bind_address directive in my Postfix config isn't working.

The pertinent parts of main.cf are:
`inet_interfaces = all smtp_bind_address = 66.42.208.244`

The pertinent parts of master.cf are:
`smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=autoresponder:dummy -o smtp_bind_address=66.42.208.244`

The actual IP address the mail comes from does not change to 66.42.200.244. From everything I have researched, the above should work.

I'm needing the IP address to change.